# Can stat show if file is hidden?

Tags: command-line, macos, stat, xattr

I'm using stat like this:

```
stat -f "%Sp %p %l %Su %u %Sg %g %z %a %N %Y"  /*
```

I need also to tell if the file is hidden or not (MacOS).
The `.` notation is not enough. MacOS hides more files.

For example, this is what I need:

```
ls -lO                                                                
total 9
drwxrwxr-x  32 root  admin  sunlnk            1024 Jun  4 22:00 Applications
drwxr-xr-x  66 root  wheel  sunlnk            2112 Feb 18 23:23 Library
drwxr-xr-x@  9 root  wheel  restricted         288 Jan  1  2020 System
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  admin  sunlnk             224 May 18 08:12 Users
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel  hidden             128 Jun  7 12:49 Volumes
drwxr-xr-x@ 38 root  wheel  restricted,hidden 1216 Jan  1  2020 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel  hidden              64 Jun  6  2020 cores
dr-xr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  hidden            4602 Jun  1 14:24 dev
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel  restricted,hidden   11 Jan  1  2020 etc -> private/etc
```

I need to run it as one command for sake of processing speed.
My goal is all from my above stat plus the 5th column of the `ls` command.
Any hints?

I've noticed that `%T` prints `@` for hidden items. It could however show it also for other reasons. Can this be used or not?

It no `stat` solution is found, is there a way to merge `stat` results with the extra `ls -lO` column on a command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If macos `stat` is like FreeBSD's, the flags can be expressed in the `format` specification with `%f` for the numeric form or `%Sf` for the decoded text form like in `ls -lo`.

See `man stat`, `man chflags` and `man ls` on your system for details.